# I have input checkbox array and want to insert in DB using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Im new to ruby on rails I would like to insert an array of checkbox but it only insert the whole array data ["PMT", "MHT"] in one row in mysql. What I want is to create one to many db insert in db.

Currently result

```
 +-------------+------------+
 | id |  company_name       |
 +-------------+------------+
 |  1 | ["MHT, "PMT"]       |
 +-------------+------------+
```

Expected Result

```
 +-------------+------------+
 | id |  company_name       |
 +-------------+------------+
 |  1 | MHT                 |
 |  2 | PMT                 |
 +-------------+------------+
```

Controller

```
     def create
        ebookAssignedCompanies = EbookCompanyAssigned.create(ebook_company_assigned_param)
        ebookAssignedCompanies.save 
     end

     private

     def ebook_company_assigned_param
        params.permit(company_name:[])
     end
```

View

```
      <% @companies.each do |company| %>
      <input type="checkbox" name = "company_name[]" id = "<%= company.id%>" value = "<%= company.company_name %>" class = "checkbox"> 
      <% end %>
```

Need help for this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be creating an array in the companies field. You want to change your database setup to reflect your expected result. I presume you want the user to make a selection from a list of companies you have stored in the database. The checkbox dropdown list is created in the view, not in the database. "[]" is an empty array, not a visible checkbox.

Comment: the companies is from model and loop with checkbox. yes you are correct the user to make a selection from a list of companies. but my problem doesnt insert correctly. it only insert ["MHT, "PMT"]. Do you have sample

Answer (score 0):

First change your database so that each company is on its own row and has its own id. Do a rake db:rollback to get rid of the current table and delete that migration from the db folder in the rails app. Then do rails generate migration Companies name:string  to generate a new migration, then rake db:migrate to activate the new table.  Then I would suggest you use the simple_form gem and learn from their site how to do a selection from a dropdown list. (after you seed the database with some names). Your confusion involves the word "array." Take it out of your thinking through this particular problem. Yes, you will get an array of companies when you ask for Company.all, but that's a different story for a different time.